# background timer in c++ using async

Tags: c++, asynchronous, atomic

i want to have a timer running in the background of my program while i do other stuff.

My program looks like:

```
void timer(int number)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(number));
    std::cout << "executing someFunction()";
}

int function1()
{
    int number = 3;
    auto future = std::async(timer, number)

    int choice;
    std::cout << "please enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> choice;
    while (choice != 0)
    {
        std::cout << choice << std::endl;
        std::cout << "please enter a number: ";
        std::cin >> choice;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int num_rows = function1();
}
```

Headers are:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>
```

Problem is, after calling the function "timer" with async, it doesn't stop which causes function1 to be stuck as well.

I've understood there is no option to cancel a thread (yet) and to do so I have to pass an "atomic variable" flag to the async task. Could someone please show me an example?

other sources:
[c++ background timer (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777638/c-background-timer)
[is there a way to cancel/detach a future in c++11? (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086622/is-there-a-way-to-cancel-detach-a-future-in-c11)

Comment: Your code doesn't compile because `auto timer` conflicts with `timer` function name

Comment: mac os x. Is there a platform independent way to get the background timer?

Comment: ah sorry, my mistake. i didnt copy & paste and changed some names to keep the code easier to read. my original code has different names.

Comment: I've never worked with Qt before and prefer Xcode since i just learned how to use it.  another solution could be ending `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(number));` is that even possible?